# Can we embed our "Google my business reviews" inside our SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, google-reviews

We have a google account with the "Google my business reviews". And we have our intranet developed using SharePoint Online modern experience. So can we embed our "Google my business reviews" inside our SharePoint Online page? If this is not possible, then what are the other approaches to show "Google my business reviews" inside SharePoint modern page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could embed an iframe possibly linking to a widget such as:

https://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/v2/?pid=ChIJ-_MFHItZwokRxZa3KrlZxiA

https://gmb.reviewsmaker.com/widget/load/?pid=ChIJ-_MFHItZwokRxZa3KrlZxiA

Notice the pid= variable, this is the place ID of your location - simply swap the place ID in the URL above and use it with an iframe widget, it should load the content directly within your pages.